# Подскажите пожалуйста как сдвинуть картинку вправо как на макете?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Не понимаю как сдвинуть картинку с классом "header__book" вправо, чтобы основной текст не сбился.
html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&family=Open+Sans+Condensed:wght@300;700&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header__inner">
                <nav class="menu">
                    <ul class="menu__list">
                        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__list-link" href="#">Главная</a></li>
                        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__list-link" href="#">о театре</a></li>
                        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__list-link" href="#">Наши постановки</a></li>
                        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__list-link" href="#">партнеры театра</a></li>
                        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__list-link" href="#">контакты</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <a class="phone" href="tel:74951234567">
                    +7 495 123-45-67
                </a>
            </div>


            <div class="header__book-inner">

            </div>

            <div class="header__book">

                <h1 class="header__title">
                    Большой театр
                </h1>
                <p class="header__subtitle">
                    Большо́й теа́тр — петербургский театр, существовавший в 1784—1886 годах, <br>
                    с 1886 года — Петербургская консерватория. Первое постоянное в <br>
                    Санкт-Петербурге, крупнейшее в России и одно из крупнейших театральных <br>
                    зданий в Европе XVIII.
                </p>
                <button type="submit" class="afisha">АФИША</button>
                <div class="header__img">
                    <img class="header__book" src="/images/header__book.png" alt="header__book">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="rotate__inner">
            <div class="rotate__social-info">
                <h2 class="text">контактная информация</h2>
                <span class="span__border"></span>
                <div class="img">
                    <img class="rotate__img" src="/images/rotate__inst.png" alt="">
                    <img class="rotate__img" src="/images/rotate__face.png" alt="">
                    <img class="rotate__img" src="/images/rotate__vk.png" alt="">
                    <img class="rotate__img" src="/images/rotate__youtube.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </header>

</body>

</html>
```

css

```
.header{
    background: url("/images/header__img.png")  no-repeat  center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1170px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.body{
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.header__inner{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100px;
}

.menu__list{
    white-space:nowrap;
    display: flex;
}

.menu__item{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu__item:hover, .menu__item:focus, .menu__item:active{
    opacity: .70;
}

.phone{
    white-space:nowrap;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #D1A954;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.header__img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 1045px;
}

.menu__list-link{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.rotate__inner{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
}

.rotate__social-info{
    background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.75);
    width: 150px;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: space-between;
}


.text{
    display: block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    position: relative;
    top: 35%;
    float: right;
    font-family: Open Sans Condensed;
    color: #C4C4C4;
    padding-top: 65%;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.img{
    position: relative;
    top: 60%;
}

.rotate__img{
    display: block;
    padding-left: 50%;
    margin-left: -13px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.span__border{
    display: block;
    width: 3px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #C4C4C4;
    position: relative;
    top: 60%;
    left: 50%;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

.header__book{
    padding-top: 300px;
}



.header__title{
    max-width: 540px;
    height: 68px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 64px;
    line-height: 87px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space:nowrap;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.header__subtitle{
    max-width: 580px;
    height: 79px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 21px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Open Sans;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.afisha{
    padding: 17px 47px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #D1A954;
    border:none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    
}

.afisha:hover, .afisha:focus, .afisha:active{
    background: #b18e45;
}
```

Comment: О каком макете идёт речь?

Comment: простите пожалуйста, забыл добавить скрины..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подобные элементы делите на части, они же располагаются горизонтально.
Проще всего будет это делать с использованием [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

```css
.header__book {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__book">
  <div class="left">
    <h1 class="header__title">
      Большой театр
    </h1>
    <p class="header__subtitle">
      Большо́й теа́тр — петербургский театр, существовавший в 1784—1886 годах, <br> с 1886 года — Петербургская консерватория. Первое постоянное в <br> Санкт-Петербурге, крупнейшее в России и одно из крупнейших театральных <br> зданий в Европе XVIII.
    </p>
    <button type="submit" class="afisha">АФИША</button>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class=" header__img">
      <img class="header__book" src="//i.imgur.com/3h6QGa1.png" alt="header__book">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, она встала справа, но как теперь поднять блок картинки? У нас же стоит отступ в 300 у .header__book

Comment: "Поднять", то есть расположить его вертикально по центру относительно текста справа?

Comment: Расположить его вертикально справа выше чем сам текст, как показано на макете. Просто в голове не укладывается как мы можем задать ему другую высоту, так как мы уже отступили в самом начале у header__book 300 px для того, чтобы сделать отступ для текста. Если я правильно понимаю, то нам нужно заехать как-то выше, игнорируя отступ у header__book.

Comment: Смотрите под другим углом, нам нужно просто разместить блок `.left` по центру вертикальной оси, тогда визуально получим то, что нужно по макету. Это можно сделать при помощи свойства `align-items: center`. Изменил ответ, обратите внимание.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Вы очень помогли!